# Import expressions from a file without it getting evaluated?

Tags: import, evaluation

How can I import a file without its expressions being evaluated ? 
E.g. assume that the file "test.m" contains just the list

```
{a, a + b + b + c, d}
```

If I use

```
Get["test.m"]
```

I obtain

> `{a, a + 2 b + c, d}`

although I would like to get the unevaluated expression.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [`ReadList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList) instead. For example:

```
ReadList[
    StringToStream @ "{a,a+b+b+c,d}",
    Hold[Expression]
]
```

> {Hold[{a, a + b + b + c, d}]}

Answer (score 4):

Also possible are

```
Import["test.m",{"Package","HeldExpressions"}]
```

returning

```
  {HoldComplete[{a, a + b + b + c, d}]}
```

and

```
 Import["test.m",{"Package","InactivatedExpressions"}]
```

giving

```
{{a, Inactive[Plus][a, b, b, c], d}}
```